# Simulate an North/South window border double click in Windows 7 or Windows 8 C#

Tags: c#, windows, api, border, native

I would like to simulate (programatically send) a double click on the North/South window border, in order to make Windows resize my window (make its height the same as the work area, while keeping its width, and X coordinate). How can I achieve that?

Basically I am trying to create a button which will use the native Windows way to do this. I don't want to manually resize the window because that way, when I would drag the window by the title bar, the window won't get restored to the previous size.

Also, I don't want to simply have a solution like moving the pointer on the corder, sending the double click and moving the pointer back. What I am trying to do is to make it totally programatically, I mean, to send the same message Windows receives when I double click on a window North/South border.